# Mapstruct results in "unrecommended usage of private members" warning by quarkus-maven-plugin

Tags: java, quarkus, mapstruct

How to resolve the following warning from the quarkus maven plugin?

> Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans

My code looks like this:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = SampleFactory.class)
public interface SampleMapper {
// mapping functions
}
```

The generated Impl class looks like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleMapperImpl implements SampleMapper {

    @Inject
    private SampleFactory sampleFactory;
    // mapping functions
}
```

The warning suggests to make the sampleFactory member package-private. Is there a possiblity to configures this, e.g. with an annotation?
The current mapstruct (1.4.2) [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#injection-strategy) states you can only configure an injection strategy. However, configuring the visibility of the injected member is not possible - is it?

Settings:

- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.1
- mapstruct 1.4.2.Final
- Java 14.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to constructor injection strategy will resolve the warning. It’s also recommended by MapStruct:

```
It is recommended to use constructor injection to simplify testing.
```

Field injection on private members requires CDI implementations to use reflection. Quarkus tries to avoid reflection in order to be able to compile with GraalVM‘s native-image compiler. Also, using reflection is simply not necessary here, so we should avoid it.

Comment: Thanks @rowing-ghoul 
Using constructor injection strategy resolves the issue. :-) 
Do you know why map-struct does not use this constructor injection strategy as default?

Comment: @JaquelineSchweigert I think field injection is more intuitive to programmers (at least it is to me). But thinking about it and using DI techniques for a while, you'll realize that constructor injection is much easier to deal with. There is a feature request in the MapStruct repo about this: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1973